# Parsing a website with Jersey, Tomcat, and Java - Encoding issue

Tags: java, tomcat, encoding, jersey, response

Here's my objective: Given a predefined top level domain and a generic search URL with an appended input query passed as a parameter, download said website's source and display it in the browser.

Eventually I will utilize various parsing techniques (substring, lol) to extract and marshal the data with JaxWS + POJOs, but I need to see raw HTML output to know my program understands its encoding properly.

I have gone from a Response return to a simple String return because I am getting gibberish encoding.  I have tried to set encoding 1000 different ways, but it doesn't seem to matter.

Note: There are other methods that I use to marshal data and such, but I have reduced the issue down to two troublesome methods.

```
public List<String> DownloadResultSource(URL url)
{
    List<String> source = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader br;
    String curLine = null;

    try
    {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
        while((curLine = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            source.add(curLine);
        }

        return source;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and

```
@GET
@Path("/{parameter}")
//@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML + ";charset=utf-8")
public String searchSites(@PathParam("parameter") String parameter,
        @DefaultValue("") @QueryParam("query") String query)
{           
        //crawl website with specified query
        Crawler crawler = new Crawler();

        //DEBUG
        Host host = hostEnum.STACKOVERFLOW.getHost();
        try
        {
            List<String> source = crawler.DownloadResultSource(new URL(host.getTopLevelDomain() + host.getDefaultSearch(query)));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(new URL(host.getTopLevelDomain() + host.getDefaultSearch(query)));
            for(String line : source)
            {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            return sb.toString();
            //return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(sb.toString()).build();
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.toString();
        }
        // end DEBUG

        // ORIGINAL return marshalResponse(crawler.SearchHost(hostEnum.STACKOVERFLOW, query));
    }

    return null;
}
```

Like I said I'm getting gibberish output, less the line I append of the raw URL (sb.append(new URL...).

Example response below.  Remember it's String currently, not Response return, though Response.....build() yields the same results:

> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=my+search+query ��}yw�H��������n'�b_�9BKw��t����y�����$#Py��|��VHh9�[��AQw��������o�*[�~�A�d��==!t3����6L��q�q}}�*�|�i��R��/:��IT#Oa�={����'6"Or����:���
>   �A�]��q9��i-

Potential curveball: I'm developing on Windows via Eclipse, though the Tomcat server is sitting on an Ubuntu Server I use the HTML manager to promote code.  Maybe there's a lack of UTF-8 support on Ubuntu?  I wouldn't think so, but I'm at my wit's end.

EDIT - More Info:
The project is a Maven project, here is the Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>my package</groupId>
  <artifactId>my project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

My Web.xml specifies UTF-8, thus: 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found, not the one I wanted, was the website is responsible for sending gibberish back.  I tried a similar website which returned the source code as expected.

No amount of specified cookies or user agents would change my results with the first site, so I have come to the conclusion that it is intentional data obfuscation from crawlers.